# Including a js or css file in velocity template

Tags: velocity

I tried to add a js file or css file as i mentioned below in the .vm file

```
   <script src='/templates/jquery-1.6.2.js>
```

it didn't work.
But when i tried adding as given below it worked

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 #include( "jquery-1.6.2.js" )
 </script>
```

But the issue is in the browser if do view source even the jquery-1.6.2.js code also appears.It doesnot hide the js code. Is there any alternate way to add the js or css file in velocity template ??

Comment: Sorry, but I think you should stop at this point and learn some html basics before going further.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone comes across this question, there is a straightforward way to include CSS styles in a Velocity template. I had a need to add some overrides to a .vm file, and putting a `<style>` tag with the appropriate rules inside `<body>` worked. I initially had the `<style>` inside the `<head>` tag but that wasn't being picked up by the parser for some reason. It looked fine in  IE 8, FF 3.6, and Chrome.

Comment: I cann't get this including to work Chris. Maybe you can answer my question on the subject http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121589/how-to-include-a-static-or-uploaded-file-in-velocity-macro-via-include