# How to include a static or uploaded file in Velocity macro via #include

Tags: velocity

I am trying to optimize some mobile web pages (or number of server requests more accurately)  by in-lining some CSS in the HTML downloaded with initial request.

These pages are delivered from our Vosao-based CMS, and use Apache Velocity macros.

This works fine, as expected.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/file/downloads/contact.css"
```

This fails

```
<style>
#include( "/file/downloads/contact.css" )
</style>
```

as Velocity cannot find the file, with this output

```
org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource '/file/downloads/contact.css'
```

and this in logs

```
org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.CommonsLogLogChute log: ResourceManager : unable to find resource '/file/Downloads/contact.css' in any resource loader.
E 2012-06-20 13:59:19.688
org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.CommonsLogLogChute log: #include(): cannot find resource '/file/Downloads/contact.css', called at vm[line 7, column 3]
```

I have read the velocity documentation (about resource ROOT property) and even spent some time on the source code. I've played with the properties for that at load time....and no luck.

How can I get Velocity to do an include of either a static file in my /war dir, or getter it to include from a path?

Comment: I fixed the formatting. You just have to select it and press Ctrl+K. :)

Comment: I've never tried to include an external CSS file in that manner. Using <link> has worked for me, as well as adding actual CSS rules within a <style> tag.

Comment: Yes, using <link> works fine, because you are just "echoing" the name of the file the link has to point to. I want to include the content to reduce the number of separate http requests to the server and ensure correct CSS is present when the content is first shown.

Comment: Which resource loader are you using? Also, are there any other #include or #parse directives in the same template? If yes what path are they referencing?

Answer (score 3):

I have successfully used like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #include("my/path/to/file/file.css")
</style>
```

Maybe is your file path wrong?